# How to serve a Nuxt application with a different cli

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, web-deployment, nuxt.js

I have a pretty simple question, but after spending a couple of hours trying to find something on the internet, I've found no success at obtaining a method.

I have a nuxt.js SPA that I am building, but my company firewall seems to be blocking the content when other users try to go to the host/port that it is being served at. I have served things at this location in the same method before with no issues. The fact that I am building/serving it with the NUXT library introduced this complication with the firewall.

I would like to simply try serving the nuxt build with another service, maybe the vue-cli-service but preferably express.js, to see if those might be able to agree with the firewall.

I just don't know how to get the vue-cli-service to serve the nuxt build from the _nuxt folder (assuming that is in fact that build), or express.js either for that matter.

How would I go about doing this? When I try to just say "vue-cli-service serve" it comes back with a gripe about not being able to find the '/src/main.js,' which is of course because nuxt uses a different file structure.

Comment: Nuxt can use express or koa or their internal server wrapper. That does not matter at all when it comes to firewall. Nuxt by default serves at port localhost:3000. Probably the port is blocked on your firewall. Try host 0.0.0.0 with some other ports like 8080 or something. More info https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Wow. Thankyou. it was in fact just the port

Comment: Should post my comment as an answer?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov If you want, sure. I will be glad to give it a check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt can use express or koa or their internal server wrapper. That does not matter at all when it comes to firewall. Nuxt by default serves at port localhost:3000. Probably the port is blocked on your firewall. Try host 0.0.0.0 with some other ports like 8080 or something. More info [nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port)